How to Efficiently Upload Files in Parallel in Next.js/Node.js Using Async and S3?
I'm working on a Next.js project where I need to upload multiple files to AWS S3 in parallel. I'm using the @aws-sdk/client-s3 for uploading the files. Despite trying different approaches, my uploads are still taking longer than expected.
Here is my current code using async.queue:
const q = async.queue(
      async (task: { image: File; path: string }, callback) => {
        const { image, path } = task;
        const name = image.name;
        const type = image.type;
        const size = image.size;
        const folderPath = `${path}/`;
        const fullKey = folderPath + image.name;

        console.log(`Started uploading: ${name}`);
        const startTime = Date.now();

        try {
          const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(await image.arrayBuffer());
          const uploadParams = {
            Bucket,
            Key: fullKey,
            Body: imageBuffer,
          };

          const command = new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams);
          await s3Client.send(command);

          const newImage: IImage = {
            full_path: fullKey,
            name,
            version: 0,
            download_req: 0,
            type,
            size,
            booking_id: bookingId,
          };

          const endTime = Date.now();
          console.log(
            `Finished uploading: ${name}. Took ${endTime - startTime}ms`
          );

          await imageService.insert(newImage);
        } catch (error) {
          // throw error;
          // callback(error instanceof Error ? error : new Error(String(error)));
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
      PARALLEL_UPLOADS
    );

    // Add all images to the queue
    q.push(images.map((image) => ({ image, path })));

    // Wait for all tasks to complete
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      q.drain(resolve);
      q.error(reject);
    });

Despite setting a concurrency limit of 20, the uploads still take a significant amount of time (around 1.8 minutes for 20 images). I would like to reduce the total upload time significantly, ideally to around 20 seconds.
Questions:
How can I ensure true parallel uploads in Next.js to S3 using async?
Are there any optimizations or alternative libraries that I should consider to improve the upload performance?
Is async.queue the best approach for this use case, or is there a better pattern/library for handling high-concurrency tasks in a Next.js environment?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
